# fetch Mongodb database using Ajax when you send your data to HTML template by "res.render"

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

Can I fetch JSON data of items from this link "/items"

```
app.get("/items", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    Item.findById(req.params.id, function(err, item) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.render("buildings/items", {item : item}); 
        }
    });
});
```

I tried :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("/items")
  .then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: You did not pass params id. You should do $.getJson("/items/[yourItemId]").then.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use `res.json()`, not `res.render`. Res.render reads a local file on the server and has the capability of injecting variables into it with an object specifying them as a parameter.

If you're just wanting to get JSON back from the server, you'll use `res.json(data)`.

For example:

```
app.get('/houses/:id', (req,res,next) => {
    const {id} = req.params;
    House.findById(id)
        .then(data => {
            res.json(data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the first line of your route to this:

```
app.get("/items/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
```

and then also pass the id to your API:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("/items/123")//Don't forget the full API address!
  .then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

More information you can find [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Comment: Thank you, Vedran. still, I cannot get my MongoDB object by getJSON() and it needs to be a JSON object to be loaded. Am I right?